# How to solve a captcha code using a machine python-anticaptcha

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on creating a small program using Python that will decompile a captcha This is a picture of the captcha types that I want to solve
[image]

The problem is when you enter the image link to download it, it has changed to another image:
https://reg.nid-moi.gov.iq/captcha/default?5wyju6xn

```
from python_anticaptcha import AnticaptchaClient, ImageToTextTask

api_key = 'my_api_key'
captcha_fp = open('default.png', 'rb')
client = AnticaptchaClient(api_key)
task = ImageToTextTask(captcha_fp)
job = client.createTask(task)
job.join()
print (job.get_captcha_text())
```

Comment: the sole point of CAPTCHA is to not allow computers to solve it

Comment: you can solve capatch or recapatch by use anticaptcha or 2captcha

Comment: what about open the page with selenium, take a snapshot (you can also localize to tag), OCR?

Comment: i use requests library not python selenium